# Facebook LoginButton for Android does not take login_text and logout_text values passed from XML

Tags: android, android-layout, facebook-android-sdk

Facebook Sdk for Android does not take login_text and logout_text values passed from XML. It just ignores it. There is no documentation/example available on earth which uses this customization of the button.

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"
    style="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
    fb:login_text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
    fb:logout_text="Connecting with facebook" />
```

It always says Login In or Log Out. How can I use this property? I tried debugging through the LoginButton code but in vain. It never goes through any of the constructors of LoginButton() and hence cannot parse my custom parameters.

Did someone face this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabriel is spot on. To fix this, go to LoginButton.java in Facebook SDK and move the parseAttributes call

```
parseAttributes(attrs)
```

to the bottom so that it always runs.

Whole method will look like this :

```
public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs.getStyleAttribute() == 0) {
            // apparently there's no method of setting a default style in xml,
            // so in case the users do not explicitly specify a style, we need
            // to use sensible defaults.
            this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_loginview_text_color));
            this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_text_size));
            this.setPadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_left),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_top),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_right),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_bottom));
            this.setWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_width));
            this.setHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_height));
            this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        if(isInEditMode()) {
            // cannot use a drawable in edit mode, so setting the background color instead
            // of a background resource.
            this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_blue));
            // hardcoding in edit mode as getResources().getString() doesn't seem to work in IntelliJ
            loginText = "Log in";
        } else {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_loginbutton_blue);
            initializeActiveSessionWithCachedToken(context);
        }
    } 
    parseAttributes(attrs);
}
```

both style and login_text are taken under consideration now. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 16):

Solved!!

Add string with name "com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button" to strings.xml located in res>values>strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">Connect</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">Your Logout</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: `<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Connect</string>` works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Your first solution is correct.
It didn't worked because you've defined the style atrribute:

```
style="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style"
```

From the LoginButton source code:

```
public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs.getStyleAttribute() == 0) {
        do stuff ...
    }
}
```

So, it will only look at the defined attribute "login_text" if you leave "style" attribute undefined.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution IMHO. Making changes to SDK code is NEVER an option. Removing the style attribute, as Gabriel points  out, suffices

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just having to change the text in the FacebookSDK source.

The login string is `com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button` located in `FacebookSDK/res/values/strings.xml`

Comment: Why hack this way? There is a supported way to change the text.

Comment: if you use android studio say goodbye to this level of control

Comment: There's not supportet way anymore: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/login/widget/LoginButton.java  the method is private and you cannot call it

Answer (score 0):

As a shortcut, you can change the login button text directly in FB SDK 4.0 in com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton class->setButtonText() method

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of these solutions but nothing works, finally I came to an end with :

```
Locale loc = Locale.FRENCH;
loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
loginButton.setTextLocale(loc);
```

This changes the text to the locale you set and also the confirm dialogs, at least what I need.

Hope this helps.